# How to write pytest tests that run in 2 stages, each stage sequentially?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm writing a bunch of tests in pytest, many of which take the form (pseudo-code):

```
def test1(self, ...):
    expected_events = do_thing1_that_should_generate_events(...)
    assert wait_for_events_to_appear_in_ui(expected_events)
```

The events take a few minutes to appear in the UI, so `wait_for_events_to_appear_in_ui` polls the UI for them, with a timeout. This works, but every such test runs for a few minutes, so total run time would be long.

So, I want to run all the `do_thingX` actions first, and then run all the validations. I thought about adding the expected events to some list, and having a final test that verifies all of them - but that means that if `do_thing1`, pytest would not report `test1` as failing, but the final test - which is sub-optimal.

Ideally, the tests would look something like:

```
def test1(self, ...):
    expected_events = do_thing1_that_should_generate_events(...)
    # some kind of magic that works like yield?
    assert wait_for_events_to_appear_in_ui(expected_events)
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What is happening in the `do_thingx` functions that you are calling? what is causing them to take so long? are they making calls out to other functions? or communicating with external things like a database or webservice?

Comment: `do_thingx` is intended to trigger the tested product, and that's how it work - it sends events to a cloud storage, which takes some time to process until they appear in the cloud UI, where I look for them. I know I could look at some testability hook to short-circuit this, but this test is intended to be end-to-end, including the cloud part.

Comment: Thats what i was curious about, if this was a functional test, an integration test or an end to end test. You might want to look at pytest-parallel. I have never used it but it seems to suggest it can run tests in parallel rather than sequential.https://pypi.org/project/pytest-parallel/

Answer (score 2):

First take a look at [pytest-xdist](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-xdist/), which is for parallelizing tests among multiple processes, among other things. I don't know how well that'll work for your case though. Read on for a more specific solution.

---

You need to manage the asynchronous running of these tests inside a single test function, which you hinted at in your question. Maybe you do it with sync code, maybe you use an async framework; that's orthogonal to this. I'm going to assume you can manage this on your own, and in any event it's not a pytest-specific thing.

To get around the problem of a blanket pass/fail inside the one pytest test function, you need subtests. [pytest-subtests](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-subtests/) allows you to write subtests inside a single test function by providing a `subtests` fixture (it also supports `subTest()` from `unittest`).

Here's the provided example:

```py
def test(subtests):
    for i in range(5):
        with subtests.test(msg="custom message", i=i):
            assert i % 2 == 0
```

Output of pytest:

```
λ pytest .tmp\test-subtest.py
======================== test session starts ========================
...
collected 1 item

.tmp\test-subtest.py .F.F..                                    [100%]

============================= FAILURES ==============================
____________________ test [custom message] (i=1) ____________________

    def test(subtests):
        for i in range(5):
            with subtests.test(msg='custom message', i=i):
>               assert i % 2 == 0
E               assert (1 % 2) == 0

.tmp\test-subtest.py:4: AssertionError
____________________ test [custom message] (i=3) ____________________

    def test(subtests):
        for i in range(5):
            with subtests.test(msg='custom message', i=i):
>               assert i % 2 == 0
E               assert (3 % 2) == 0

.tmp\test-subtest.py:4: AssertionError
================ 2 failed, 1 passed in 0.07 seconds =================
```

The failed/passed numbers are a bit counter-intuitive at first glance. It looks like we have five subtests, of which two should fail; and indeed we have two reported failures. But we only have one passing test, not three. That one pass is `test_func()` itself; since the `with` block is catching the asserts inside, `test_func()` isn't failing. The other three subtests didn't fail, and therefore were not reported at all – although we do see them represented in the progress dots.

In summary: manage the tests yourself, and use [pytest-subtests](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-subtests/) to get individual reporting of the failures.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and accept if it works right!

Comment: "The other three subtests didn't fail, and therefore were not reported at all" - that sounds pretty bad. Any way around it in `pytest-subtests`?

Comment: It's a known issue; according to [this comment](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-subtests/issues/11#issuecomment-480080627), the maintainer is waiting on some functionality in pytest that allows that to be done.

Comment: Why do you feel it's pretty bad though? @Jonathan

Comment: Because I expect the number of test results to remain constants between runs. If I have 5 (sub)tests, I expect to see 5 results (2 fail +3 success in the example), plus maybe an additional outside-test result. I don't expect the number of results to change between runs. But I guess I'll have to live with it until it's fixed.